# Characteristic polynomial for the frobenious map.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Consider the Frobenius automorphism $\sigma:\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}} \to \mathbb{F}_{p^n} $ defined by $\sigma(x)=x^{p},$ where $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a finite field with $p^n$ elements. Then it is clearly $\sigma$ 
 is $\mathbb{F}_p$ linear map. My question is what is the characteristic polynomial of $\sigma$ ?

Since $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is the splitting field of $X^{p^n}-X$ over $\mathbb{F}_p,$ we have $\sigma ^n-1=0,$ thus the minimal polynomial of $\sigma$ will divide $X^n-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X].$ But I can't find characteristic polynomial of $\sigma.$ Help me. Thanks.

Comment: Oops. I had also answered this [earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95892/11619). One more reason to CWify. Doubtful whether I should initiate closing this as a duplicate now :-(

Comment: I missed that ..i got my answer..thanks  Jyrki Lahtonen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the following pieces:

- The space is $n$-dimensional, so the characteristic polynomial has degree $n$.
- The minimal polynomial $m(T)$ is a factor of the characteristic polynomial (as well as of $T^n-1$).
- If $m(T)$ has degree $m$, say, $m(T)=\sum_{i=0}^ma_iT^i\in\Bbb{F}_p[T]$, then all the $p^n$ elements of the bigger field are zeros of the polynomial $M(x)=\sum_{i=0}^ma_ix^{p^i}$ of degree $p^m$. Therefore $m\ge n$.

Comment: I have used the same argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53316/11619), and more recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2633860/11619). Switching to CW, because I strongly believe that one should not seek to get paid twice for the same work even when the compensation is in the form of internet ego points.